# Syntax to set color of LED in sense-hat using nodered

Tags: node.js, node-red, led

I am working on sense-hat using node-red. I found that, to set the four corners of the display to red, green (#00ff00), yellow and blue (0,0,255):

0,0,red,0,7,#00ff00,7,7,yellow,7,0,0,0,255

But how to set color for 2 leds in column 2 and 3 of the LED panel in rows 2-7.

Can anyone please suggest me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sidebar help for the SenseHAT node describes the required syntax:

```
Format: <x>,<y>,<colour>

x and y must either be a value from 0 to 7,
a * to indicate the entire row or column,
or a range such as 3-6.
```

> But how to set color for 2 leds in column 2 and 3 of the LED panel in rows 2-7.

If you want to set just two leds within those ranges then just pick two X/Y values within that range and set them.

```
2,2,red,2,3,red
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but the above will set all leds in 2-3 row, in 2-7 column to red. I need to set only 2 led s.

Comment: To be clear, you are asking how to set just two leds within that range? Just pick two x/y values within that range and set the pixel... have updated the answer with an example.